# What value am I getting from Date.parse()? Parsing an iso string back to a Javascript Date Object via Date.parse()

Tags: javascript

My iso string is: "2016-07-30T09:59:59.998Z"

when I use Date.parse("2016-07-30T09:59:59.998Z"), I am getting 1469872799998

using new Date("2016-07-30T09:59:59.998Z") returns me the correct answer, what value am I getting from Date.parse?

Comment: you are getting the number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`

Comment: Has this been answered?

Answer (score 0):

From the Mozilla docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse:

**Direct call:**

```
Date.parse(dateString)
```

**Implicit call:**

```
new Date(dateString)
```

**Parameters**

dateString
A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).

**Return value**

A number representing the milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC and the date obtained by parsing the given string representation of a date. If the argument doesn't represent a valid date, NaN is returned.

But you can use this to create a new date object if you wish

```
new Date(Date.parse("2016-07-30T09:59:59.998Z"))
```

However there is not much point, as you have realised you can use the string directly. The reason you can is that Date.parse is implicitly called when you create the Date object.

Comment: The **real** docs are here: [*ECMAScript® 2016 Language Specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-objects). Note that there is no mention of RFC2822 or any standard other than ISO 8601 for Dates.

Comment: Reading the specs is great, but specifications !== documentation.